# Statistical test significance

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

```
Sales      Country X    Country Y
Brand A     58616       52123
Brand B     15933       14372
Brand C     14132       11926
Brand D     9206        8747
Brand E     9249        8534
Total       107136      95702

Percentages   Country X   Country Y
Brand A        54.71%     54.46%
Brand B        14.87%     15.02%
Brand C        13.19%     12.46%
Brand D        8.59%       9.14%
Brand E        8.63%      8.92%
Total          100.00%    100.00%
```

Above two tables have sales data (Numerical and Percentages) of 5 brands and two countries. There is an increase of 14.87% to 15.02% (15933 to 14372)in Brand B. I want to ask if there is any statistical technique which can answer that this increase or change is significant or insignificant (For Brand A).

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this that need clarification. E.g.: Are you trying to make a statement about total sales or market shares?

But in principle the following needs to be considered:
Posing the the question of statistically significant differences treats sales as a random variable. Hence, to answer this question you need to make assumptions about the variance (or the full distribution) or assumptions that allow you to take measurements of the variance in some way. I don't how  this could be feasible if those two tables are all the data you have.

Comment: I want to monitor the performance of Brand B (which has 14.87% share in Country X and 15.02% share in country Y), I want to know is this difference statistically significant for Bran B? And this is month wise data, I have data of past 12 months in similar form.

Answer (score 0):

If the Percentages table was derived from Sales then you should ignore it. You can't use a paired t-test between countries X, Y on the sales table because your data is not normally distributed, so you should use a Wilcoxon rank sum test (though it fails to detect a significant difference on your data).